# How to access an exact array from the api using fetch in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I want to get images from an api , but i can't get through all the arrays to access it.
I can get only all the posts arrays , but not furthermore in a single call.
[image]

I used fetch to get my data like this:

```
getPostImages = () => {
  fetch (this.apiKey).
  then(response => { 
    if (response.ok) {
     return response.json(); 
  };
}).then((j: any) => 
{ console.log(j.data.post);
 });
}
```

How do I access all the arrays to get the images? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's better to use Angular HttpClient instead. It works in tandem with observable and provides more ways to control and transform the data.

Nevertheless you could use `Array#map` to create an array from a specific property in an array and `Array#concat` to flatten the items.

```js
images = [];

getPostImages = () => {
  fetch(this.apiKey)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      };
    })
    .then((j: any) => {
      console.log(j.data.post);
      const images = ...j.data.post.map(item => item.images);
      this.images = [].concat.apply([], images);
    });
}
```